# Function called in uitableview at cellForRowAtIndexPath makes scrolling slow

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have an image that returns everytime the user scrolls the uitableview. This code is inside:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The code that is being called is the following and creates a shadow for the image specified:

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithShadowForImageRight:(UIImage *)initialImage {

    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef shadowContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, initialImage.size.width + 10, initialImage.size.height + 10, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(initialImage.CGImage), 0, colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(shadowContext, CGSizeMake(5,-5), 10, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawImage(shadowContext, CGRectMake(0, 10, initialImage.size.width, initialImage.size.height), initialImage.CGImage);

    CGImageRef shadowedCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(shadowContext);
    CGContextRelease(shadowContext);

    UIImage * shadowedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:shadowedCGImage];
    CGImageRelease(shadowedCGImage);

    return shadowedImage;
}
```

The above code makes the scrolling slow and not smooth. Is there a way to overcome this issue by changing the code so it can load the image faster?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this *is* the make-or-break function for smooth scrolling. You need to make it as fast as you can by avoiding as much calculation as possible.

For example, you could add caching for the image processed by your `imageWithShadowForImageRight:` method: set up an instance of [`NSCache`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store processed images; key them by the index path, and avoid recomputation when the same image is requiested multiple times during the process of scrolling.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithShadowForImageRight:(UIImage *)initialImage atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    UIImage *res = [cache objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (!res) {
        // get the shadowed image
        res = shadowedImage;
        [cache setObject:res forKey:indexPath];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering dasblinkenlight. I will try your advice and let everyone know what happens. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your advice worked it moves nicely now. I will try to avoid more processing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a static shadow image, or does it need to be rendered independently for each image? Dynamic shadows are an expensive operation, especially coupled with scrolling.

Also, can you call this method for all your images in viewDidLoad? That way, you don't have to render the shadows while also devoting computation time to drawing the scroll view and populating the table cells.

Comment: Jeremy thanks for answering. No I can not use a static shadow image because the images change dynamically for each row. Neither viewDidLoad can help. The images come from the server side.